# Are there limits to tracking fields history?

Tags: fields, history-tracking

For tracking fields, is there a hard limit of the number of fields that one can track on a custom object?

I've done a [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=salesforce%20tracking%20limits) and found some results but they're from 2012 and some are posted on the forum. They don't seem official.

Would anyone have a canonical number of fields that allow tracking per custom objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can track upto 20 standard and custom fields per custom object.

To track field history for custom objects:

1. From Setup, click Create | Objects.
2. Click Edit next to the name of
       the custom object.
3. Select the Track Field History checkbox.
4. Click Save.
5. Click Set History Tracking in the Custom Fields & Relationships section.
   This section allows you to set a custom object’s history for both standard and custom fields.
6. Choose the fields you want tracked.
   You can select up to 20 standard and custom fields per object. You can’t track:
   Formula, roll-up summary, or auto-number fields
   Created By and Last Modified By
7. Click Save.Salesforce tracks history from this date and time forward. Changes made prior to this date and time are not included.

Look into this [What is the best workaround for the 20 field history tracking cap?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/39956/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-20-field-history-tracking-cap/39960#39960)

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some peer digging, there's an application cheat sheet that outlines the application limits on tracking. [It's set to 20.](http://j.mp/sf-app-limits) or it's also found here: https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf