# Field History tracking limit

Tags: field-history

I know that we could track 20 standard and custom fields from custom objects.

I thought we cannot track more than 20 fields per object.

But in sandbox, i have a custom object where there are more than 30 fields that are tracked.

When I add more, it doesn't give an error and starts tracking them.

Is this limit increased over 20?

Thank you.

Comment: The limit can increased, you are not able to see the limits page to see if it has however, in sandbox I don't think it's enforced. Try doing the same in Prod, or log a SF support case and they can tell you what it is.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/39956/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-20-field-history-tracking-cap

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, you can contact Salesforce support probably log a case to increase this limit.