# Custom Track Field history mechanism with reporting

Tags: reporting, limits, history-tracking

I have the task to create a function of tracking field changes on objects which are associated with some relations(master-detail, lookup) and show that changes on report for all track history objects. For example, I created two of them.

[image]

[image]

At the beginning I thought about the standard mechanism of "track field history" but ...... **salesforce limits** ....

- we cannot track more than 20 fields per object
- we cannot see changes in long text area

**Report limits:**

- Reporting on field history tracking of a custom object is **not
  available if the object is a detail of a Master-Detail Relationship**.

So I thought about the creation of the custom object which stores the changes of these objects(answer and question). This solution would allow me to create a report of changes in two objects.

I found a similar solution here:
[What is the best workaround for the 20 field history tracking cap?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/39956/what-is-the-best-workaround-for-the-20-field-history-tracking-cap/39960)

On the other hand I would like to save the values ​​of the objects to one "history object". How is the best possible way to to this? Maybe proces builder or workflow rule to create the record when the appropriate field is change?

What do you think about these solutions? I ask for your help.

## **My question:**

What is the best practise to do the following use case:

- Track fields changes from two or more objects(Proces Builder,
  Workflow, other) and save that changes in specyfic custom object i.e. "QuestionHistory"?

--edit

1)

I checked, and unfortunately processes are too poor to solve the cases that have been described above.

Comment: Could you clarify your question as to what you're struggling with? Right now your question seems a bit vague and subject to opinion (use of "best"). What exactly are you asking us? Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yea, you have right. Question changed.